# How MAX() fucntion works

Tags: database, oracle, max

I'm trying to understand MAX function in oracle, I'm unable to understand how it works when a column is concatenated.

```
select max(effdate) from
(
select to_date('30-SEP-2023','DD-MON-YYYY') effdate from dual
union
select to_date('31-DEC-2022','DD-MON-YYYY') EFFDATE from dual
);
```

Result: as expected

> 30-SEP-2023 00:00:00

Query 2:

```
select max(effdate||' ==== '||amt) from
(
select to_date('30-SEP-2023','DD-MON-YYYY') effdate, 14 amt from dual
union
select to_date('31-DEC-2022','DD-MON-YYYY') EFFDATE, 10 amt from dual
);
```

Result:

> 31-DEC-2022 00:00:00 ==== 10

I was expecting: 30-SEP-2023 ==== 14

Query 3:

```
select max(effdate||' ==== '||amt) from
(
select to_date('30-SEP-2023','DD-MON-YYYY') effdate, 14 amt from dual
union
select to_date('30-DEC-2022','DD-MON-YYYY') EFFDATE, 10 amt from dual
);
```

Result:

> 30-SEP-2023 00:00:00 ==== 14

Could someone explain how MAX() works here?

Comment: And to answer the question title, `MAX()` calculates the expression for every row, sorts results in ascending order and picks the first item. It doesn't remember or consider the original cells, or implement anything too fancy.

Answer (score 1):

After concatenating a date with a string, it turns into a string, therefore, the maximum value is derived alphabetically, not based on date order :

Here how to get the max based on date then by amt :

```
SELECT effdate || ' ==== ' || amt 
FROM (
  SELECT to_date('30-SEP-2023','DD-MON-YYYY') effdate, 14 amt FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT to_date('31-DEC-2022','DD-MON-YYYY') EFFDATE, 10 amt FROM dual
)
ORDER BY effdate DESC, amt DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

Query 2 is effectively:

```sql
WITH sample_data (effdate, amt) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2023-09-30', 14 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-12-31', 10 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT MAX(
         TO_CHAR(
           effdate,
           (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
         )
         || ' ==== '
         || TO_CHAR(amt)
       ) AS maximum
from   sample_data;
```

as you are performing an implicit cast from a `DATE` to a string and so Oracle will implicitly call `TO_CHAR` on the date using the current value of the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model for the date.

If you use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY';
```

and run the query then the output is:

| MAXIMUM |
| --- |
| 31-DEC-2022 ==== 10 |

Since it will format the dates as `31-DEC-2022` and `30-SEP-2023` and when comparing strings `'31'` is greater than `'30'` so it will take the maximum alphabetic value (and not the maximum date value).

If you use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

And then run exactly the same query, the output is:

| MAXIMUM |
| --- |
| 2023-09-30 00:00:00 ==== 14 |

The implicit format model has been changed and so the order of the components of the date have changed and the alpha-numeric sort order of the characters in the strings corresponds to the order of the dates so you get your expected output.

Query 3 has the same issues but you have the output `30-SEP-2023` and `30-DEC-2022` and `30-S` is greater than `30-D` so it coincidentally happens that the greater date has the month abbreviation that sorts greatest alphabetically.

The conclusion to take from this is to:

1. Never rely on implicit string conversions; and
2. If you want to sort data then do not convert it (especially implicitly) to an inappropriate data-type.

---

From Oracle 12 you could use:

```sql
WITH sample_data (effdate, amt) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2023-09-30', 14 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-12-31', 10 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
from   sample_data
ORDER BY effdate DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

To get the maximum date and the corresponding `amt`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yxFp8X0i)

Answer (score -1):

The MAX() function in SQL is an aggregate function that is used to find the maximum value of a specified column or expression within a group of rows. It works as follows:

```
Syntax:
```

MAX(expression)

Where expression is typically the column name or an expression involving columns.

Working Principle:

```
When used in a query with a GROUP BY clause, MAX() operates within each group defined by the GROUP BY clause.
When used without a GROUP BY clause, MAX() operates on the entire result set, returning a single maximum value from the specified column or expression.
```

Example:

Consider a table named Employees with columns EmployeeID and Salary. We want to find the maximum salary among all employees.

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) AS MaxSalary
FROM Employees;

This query will return the maximum salary (MaxSalary) from the Employees table.

Use Cases:
    It is commonly used to find the highest or maximum value of a numeric column, such as salaries, prices, or quantities.
    It can also be used with date/time columns to find the latest or maximum date/time.

Handling NULL Values:
    The MAX() function ignores NULL values when determining the maximum value. If all values in the specified column are NULL, MAX() returns NULL.
    To handle NULL values differently, you can use the IFNULL() function (in MySQL) or the COALESCE() function (in Oracle, SQL Server, etc.) to replace NULL values with a specific value before applying MAX().

Performance Considerations:
    While MAX() is a powerful function, it can sometimes be inefficient when used in large datasets or complex queries. Consider indexing columns if performance becomes an issue.
```

In summary, the MAX() function in SQL is used to find the maximum value of a specified column or expression within a group of rows, or across the entire result set. It is a handy tool for data analysis and reporting tasks.